# Flutter Launcher icon not getting changed?

Tags: android, image, dart, flutter

Am new to Flutter. I gone through the flutter documentation and followed the steps to configure custom launcher icons for my flutter project but app Launcher icon is not getting changed? Not sure what am missing.

[image]

Code:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter  
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.0"

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "icon/icon.png"
  android: true 
  ios: true
```

Comment: It's always better to share the code instead of image and explain problem in detail with your approach

Comment: Did you run `flutter pub get` and `flutter pub pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main` on the terminal?

Comment: @JeromeEscalante How can this be a duplicate, this seems to be an issue with the library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the application launcher icon on Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928702/how-to-change-the-application-launcher-icon-on-flutter)

Answer (score 67):

you have to get the package and then after run following command to change the icon.

```
 $ flutter pub pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

Comment: This command is now deprecated (not yet removed), change to `dart run flutter_launcher_icons:main`.

Answer (score 24):

1. Add **flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.3** code Plugin to pubspec.yaml
2. in **pubspec.yaml :**

   ```
   flutter_icons:
     image_path_android: "images/logoapp.png"
     image_path_ios: "images/logoapp.png"
     android: true
     ios: true
   ```
3. run command : **flutter pub get**
4. run command : **flutter pub pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main**
5. run command : **flutter clean**
6. run command : **flutter run**

it worked for me

Answer (score 18):

Able to change Now after following below Steps.

1. Add flutter_launcher_icons code Plugin to pubspec.yaml as mentioned in question
2. In Command prompt run below commands

   - flutter pub get
   - **flutter pub pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main**
3. And it worked
4. Launcher Icons I generated using external website https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

Answer (score 6):

I wasn't using `flutter_launcher_icons`, I was using just Image Asset Studio in the Android project. It seemed that in certain situations it wasn't updating my Adaptive Icon on Android.

To fix it, I opened the Android module (right click on the `android/` folder in the Flutter view, then select Flutter | Open Android Module in Android Studio). From there, open the `res/` folder and delete everything that looks like `foreground.xml`. AFAICT this is what is generated by Image Asset Studio as part of the Adaptive Icon.

Then recreate the Adaptive Icon via Image Asset Studio.

At this point my Flutter cache was corrupted, so I had to run `flutter pub cache repair` (I mention this because maybe somehow that is what fixed it, but I doubt it). Run the app and then voila, the icon updated.

Answer (score 4):

there is two way to update app icon

1) first way

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter  

  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.5"

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "icon/appicon.png"
  android: true 
  ios: true
```

run this two command

```
flutter pub get

flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

2) if above not work then below solutions (change in native)

you can change appicon from Image Asset, right click on main folder of your project structure and go new -> Image Asset , now just select your icon and finish it, Android studio will generate all necessary icons for you.

[image: here look of Image Asset]

similarly you can change appicon for ios, go

ios -> Runner -> Assets.xcassets -> Appicon.appiconset

then replace icons with your new icons

that's it!

Answer (score 4):

For me the folder `drawable-v24` was a problem. After removing `foreground.xml` from there it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Those who had faced problems in changing the flutter icon in VS code, go to android/app/build.gradle. Then change the value of the following two properties:

```
// minSdkVersion 26
// targetSdkVersion 30
```

Then the same process.

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following [image: flutter launcher icon docs] and then run your app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First add flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1 code Plugin to pubspec.yaml

in pubspec.yaml file:

1. flutter_icons:
   image_path_android:"images/logoapp.png"
   image_path_ios:"images/logoapp.png"
   android:true
   ios:true
2. check iOS -Folder -> Runner -> Assets.xcassets -> AppIcon.appiconset:
   if duplicates exist delete them.

run commands : flutter pub get
run commands : flutter pub pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
run commands : flutter clean
run commands : flutter run

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting any errors when they try to run `flutter pub pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main`, you may have not added Flutter to PATH. Follow this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62995926/7145285) to add Flutter to Path.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there is a `Contents.json` file under `ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset` that contains the name of the previous png files, which didn't match the new files that was replaced in that folder.

I properly updated the json file with the new file names, then removed the application on my simulator and run the build again. Then I could see the new icon on ios.

Answer (score 0):

If you have flavors in IOS,

Goto `Xcode` > `Runner` > `Build Settings` > `Asset Catalog Compiler - options` > `Primary App Icon Set Name` and add values for each flavor

Answer (score 0):

the library now requires

```
flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon.png"
```

The difference is `flutter_icons:` or `flutter_launcher_icons:`